# Exercise on Picard's theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p$ be a cubic polynomial which has at least two distinct zeros. If $f$ is a non constant entire function, prove that the range of $p\left(f(z)\right)$ on $\mathbb{C} $ is the entire complex plane.

Comment: The statement is incorrect.  Where is the problem from?

Comment: $p'$ needs to have two distinct zeros.

Comment: I took the exercise from old qualifying exams. I double checked and the statement is the one i wrote. However i dont know if there is any mistake in the statement.

Comment: There is. $p(z) = 1 + z^3$ has three distinct zeros, but $p(e^z) = 1 + e^{3z}$ does not attain the value $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. In the case you said about p' what is the aolution?

Comment: Write down a general formula for $p(z)$. Let $w$ be any complex value and look at solutions to $p(f(z)) = w$ and use Picard: there is max one single value not taken by $f$. Call this value $s$ and let $w = p(s)$. You need to show that there is another complex value $q \not= s$ such that $p(q) = w$ (why?). This places some constraints on $p$ (just like Daniel said). Can you take it from here?